# selenium RC- change default port 4444 port .if the port is busy at runtime

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

How to handle the scenario while running SELENIUM RC.If we get the default port 4444 is busy.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to check whether port 4444 is busy. If it is busy then set your RC to use a different port.

```
   static int port=4444;
          try {
             ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
             //Checking whether 4444 is closed or not
             if(!serverSocket.isClosed())
                port=5555;//Or whatever port you like
             //Now start selenium server
             RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
             rcc.setPort(port);
             SeleniumServer server = new SeleniumServer(false, rcc);
             server.start();  }

          catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); }
```